# themes.xml not setting app bar colour in dark theme

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

In my themes.xml I have

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
```

This sets the app bar colour AOK

However if I set my themes.xml (night) to

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
```

And I engage dark theme, the colour setting is ignored

Can anybody please explain what I am missing ?

Comment: Post your app theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Material Design then add this in your AppTheme

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge"
```